# How to get the length of a user input?

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to find the length of any string the user inputs. However, for some reason the .length() method only finds the length of the first word, and then stops.

Because of that, I decided to replace all spaces with "_" and then find the length. For some reason, the .length() method is still only finding the length of the first word. I understand that I could probably put every word of the string into an array, and then find their lengths independently, but there must be a more efficient way to do it.

I looked at many other answers. userInput.replace("\s","*"); or userInput.replace(" ","*"); does not work for me at all; it produces the exact same result as before. How can I find the length of a string without using arrays?

```
package com.skulr.challenge;
import com.skulr.challenge.Menu;


public class Challenge11 {

    static String userInput;
    static int count0;

    static int i = 0;

    public static void method1() {

        System.out.println("Input a message and we will\ncalculate it's length\n");
        System.out.print("- ");

        userInput = Menu.menuScanner.next();

        userInput = userInput.replace("\\s","_");
        System.out.println(userInput);
        count0 = userInput.length();


        System.out.println("Your string is: " + count0 + " characters long.");

    }

}
```

Comment: Read the javadoc of Scanner. What does it do? What is the definition of a token? What does its next() method do? Then read the javadoc of its nextLine() method. Also, learn to use a debugger, or at least to print the values of your variables. userInput is not what you think it is. String.length() obviously does what its documentation says it does. Otherwise, it would be a huge bug, and it would have been fixxed for a long time. When something doesn't work as expected, there is a 99.9999999% chance of being a bug in your code, not in the standard libraries.

Comment: I'm thinking you are only retrieving the first word of the user input, the issue is not the length it's the way you retrieve user input.

Answer (score 0):

Scanner use to get token(Split string by some deliminator, default is space) of string for processing.

If you change next() method with nextLine() then it will return entire line without token.

Try.

userInput = Menu.menuScanner.nextLine();
 count0 = userInput.length();
 System.out.println("Your string is: " + count0 + " characters long.");

OR

Scanner sc = Menu.menuScanner.useDelimiter("\n");
userInput = Menu.menuScanner.next();
count0 = userInput.length();
System.out.println("Your string is: " + count0 + " characters long.");

Answer (score -3):

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(System.in);

    String userString = inputStream.nextLine();
    System.out.println(userString.length());
}
```

Comment: Provide comments. Everyone's here to learn, not to copy-and-paste.

Comment: Thanks, I see what I've done wrong here thanks to you and the previous posters.